# Checking subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

Let $B$ be a fixed matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ and 
$W=\{{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} :AB=BA}\}$

Then is $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ ?

I have tried this so far:

a) The zero vector is in $W$ as $\theta_{n\times n}B=B\theta_{n\times n}$

b) If I take to vectors $X$ and $Y$ in $W$ then add them up we get
$XB=BX$ and $YB=BY$ and $(X+Y)B=(Y+X)B$ as matrix addition is commutative. So I can say that $W$ is closed under the usual laws of addition.

c) Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X\in W$ then if $AB=BA$ we can say $(\alpha X)B=B(\alpha X)$. So $W$ is also closed under the usual laws of scalar multiplication.

Hence $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $.

Is my reasoning correct ? Guys I need your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**
Your proof is correct just I suggest to use best notation: big capitals for matrices and a little capitals for scalars. This's a hint for an alternative proof:

What we can say about the map

$$f\colon \Bbb R^{n\times n}\to \Bbb R^{n\times n},\quad  X\mapsto XB-BX\quad ?$$

How we prove the desired result using this map?

Comment: Thanks Sir. Will try to follow the correct notations from the next time onwards.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $W$ is not empty. It evidently contains the identity matrix.

If $A_0B=BA_0$ and $A_1B=BA_1$ then $(A_0+A_1)B=A_0B+A_1B=BA_0+BA_1=B(A_0+A_1)$

If $AB=BA$  then $(\alpha A)B=\alpha (AB)=\alpha (BA)=B(\alpha A)$

There is no need to prove apart that the zero matrix also does it, since it follows from the second rule when you take $\alpha=0$.

Comment: That was my first observation that $W$ should indeed contain the identity matrix. Could you please explain a bit more the second part of your argument ? I could not follow it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By second part do you mean the part with scalar $\alpha$?

Comment: No the scalar part I did understand. I was just curious why did use the property of the transpose of the matrix in part A. Could you please clarify it for me?

Comment: Oh sorry, $A'$ was not meant be the notation of the transpose. It was just meant to be another matrix next to $A$. I will repair to make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks I now understand your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

In b) what you actually want to prove is $(x+y)B=B(x+y)$. Also your notation in c) is off, replace $B$ by $x$. You sometimes miss the "for all $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$". The moment you get more confident with the notation I'd suggest using $A$, $B$ and $C$ for elements of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Your (b) is, I believe, wrong: what you must prove is

$$C,D\in W\implies C\pm D\in W\iff B(C\pm D)=(C\pm D)B\iff BC\pm BD= CB\pm DB$$

Comment: Please tell me where have I gone wrong. I could not understand your point I am sorry.

Comment: When you say "If I take to vectors x  and y  in W ...", together with your notation, I thought you actually meant vectors in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ and *not* vectors in $\;W\;$ , which in fact are matrices. The little letters let me to believe so.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding caused. I have changed the notation appropriately. Is it correct now?